# How to prove $\frac{a^2b}{ab^2+1}+\frac{b^2c}{bc^2+1}+\frac{c^2a}{a^2c+1}\ge \frac{3abc}{1+abc}$?

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $a,b,c>0.$ Prove that$$\frac{a^2b}{ab^2+1}+\frac{b^2c}{bc^2+1}+\frac{c^2a}{a^2c+1}\ge \frac{3abc}{1+abc}.$$
I got a wrong inequality after using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Actually, $$\frac{a^2b}{ab^2+1}+\frac{b^2c}{bc^2+1}+\frac{c^2a}{a^2c+1}\ge \frac{(ab+bc+ca)^2}{ab^3+bc^3+ca^3+a+b+c}\ge  \frac{3abc}{1+abc}.$$
Since $(ab+bc+ca)^2\ge 3abc(a+b+c)$ and we need to show $$(1+abc)(a+b+c)\ge ab^3+bc^3+ca^3+a+b+c \iff abc(a+b+c)\ge ab^3+bc^3+ca^3 $$which is equivalent to $$\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{a}\le a+b+c.$$The last inequality is obviously wrong because $$\frac{a^2}{b}+b\ge 2a,~~\frac{b^2}{c}+c\ge 2b,~~\frac{c^2}{a}+a\ge 2c$$
$$\implies\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{a}\ge 2(a+b+c)-(a+b+c)=a+b+c. $$
Could you please give me a hint to solve the starting inequality? Any ideas and comments are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Proof.**

We may use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality as $$\frac{a^2b}{ab^2+1}+\frac{b^2c}{bc^2+1}+\frac{c^2a}{a^2c+1}=\frac{a^2}{ab+\dfrac{1}{b}} +\frac{b^2}{bc+\dfrac{1}{c}} +\frac{c^2}{ca+\dfrac{1}{a}}  \ge \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{ab+bc+ca+\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}}.$$
And $(a+b+c)^2\ge 3(ab+bc+ca)$ then $$\frac{a^2b}{ab^2+1}+\frac{b^2c}{bc^2+1}+\frac{c^2a}{a^2c+1}\ge \frac{3(ab+bc+ca)}{ab+bc+ca+\dfrac{ab+bc+ca}{abc}}=  \frac{3abc}{1+abc}.$$
Hence, the proof is done. Equality holds iff $a=b=c=1.$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Let $abc=k$. Then,
$$\sum\dfrac{a^2b}{ab^2+\dfrac{abc}{k}}\ge\frac{3k}{1+k}\iff\sum \frac{a}{kb+c}\ge\frac{3}{1+k}$$
This is very similar to [Nesbitt's Inequality.](https://brilliant.org/wiki/nesbitts-inequality/)